# Libgdx OpenGL ES pixel shader behaves differently on android and on desktop

Tags: libgdx, mathematics, shaders, glsl, opengl-es

I'm currently working on a mobile game that ressembles a snake game ; what I wished to do was use my limited glsl knowledge to write a pixel shader that could efficiently draw a curve with a certain width between a set of a few 2D points.

This is what I managed on desktop using basic libgdx to draw on the whole screen with the shader, and for input.

[via GIPHY](https://giphy.com/gifs/26BRIaoiAywTl8QoM)

To do this, first, I find which point is closest to gl_FragCoord, then, with quite a bit of math, I calculate the equation for a curve between the half-point before that point, and the half-point after it, using this point as control point for the curve... (by half-point I mean the average between it and the point next or before it in the table)

I then use more math to calculate all the local minimums of the distance between the pixel and this curve ; check which are valid, and calculate the minimum distance between the fragment and the snake. Then I can easily check if the pixel is in the width of the snake (named W).

I hope I explained it well, because the code is not annotated at all. I was hoping people had any ideas what could make the difference between the desktop version of libgdx that works perfectly (higher up), and the android version, that does less well...

[Original Video](http://fr.tinypic.com/player.php?v=2uetr2r&s=9)

```
uniform vec2 stuff;
uniform vec2 points[10];

vec4 fragColor;

vec3 cubicsolve(float a,float b,float c,float d);

void main() {
    float tailLength = stuff.y;


    fragColor = vec4(0.,0.,0.,1.);
    vec4 primColor = vec4(92./255.,158./255.,237./255.,1.);//5C9EED
    vec4 degColor = vec4(236./255.,135./255.,192./255.,1.);//EC87C0


    int pointNum = int(stuff.x);
    vec2 F = gl_FragCoord.xy;
    float W = 10.; // width of the snake


    degColor = mix(primColor, degColor, 1.- (F.x/1920.+F.y/1080.)/2.);


    vec2 alux = points[0]-F;
    float first = alux.x*alux.x+alux.y*alux.y;
    int key = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i<pointNum-1; i++) {
        vec2 aux = points[i]-F;
        float dist2 = aux.x*aux.x+aux.y*aux.y;
        if(dist2<first) {
            first=dist2;
            key = i;
        }
    }

    float tlim = 1.00;
    if(key > pointNum-3) tlim = tailLength;

    vec2 t1,mid,t2;
    if(key == 0) {
        t1 = points[0];
        mid = points[1];
        t2 = (points[1]+points[2])/2.;
    } else {
        t1 = (points[key]+points[key-1])/2.;
        mid = points[key];
        t2 = (points[key]+points[key+1])/2.;
    }

    vec2 a = (t1-2.*mid+t2);
    vec2 b = 2.*(mid-t2);
    vec2 c = t2;
    vec2 P;


    vec2 A = 4.*a*a;
    vec2 B = 6.*a*b;
    vec2 C = 2.*b*b+4.*a*(c-F);
    vec2 D = 2.*b*(c-F);

    vec3 get = cubicsolve(A.x+A.y, B.x+B.y, C.x+C.y, D.x+D.y);
    float x[3];
    x[0] = get.x;x[1] = get.y;x[2] = get.z;

    float minDist = 1000.;

    for(int i = 0; i<3; i++) {
        float xi = x[i];
        if(xi>=1.-tlim && xi<=1.) {
            //fragColor += vec4(.01,.01,.01,.01);
            vec2 temp = a*xi*xi+b*xi+c;
            temp = temp * (temp-2.*F) + F*F;
            float tempDist = temp.x+temp.y;
            if(tempDist < minDist) minDist = tempDist;
        }
    }
    if(true) {
        vec2 temp = a*(1.-tlim)*(1.-tlim)+b*(1.-tlim)+c;
        temp = temp * (temp-2.*F)+F*F;
        float tempsol = temp.x+temp.y;
        if(tempsol < minDist) minDist = tempsol;
        temp = a*1.*1.+b*1.+c;
        temp = temp * (temp-2.*F)+F*F;
        tempsol = temp.x+temp.y;
        if(tempsol < minDist) minDist = tempsol;
    }

    if(minDist<W*W) {
        fragColor = vec4(1.,1.,1.,1.);
    }





    vec2 At = points[0];

    if((At.x-F.x)*(At.x-F.x)+(At.y-F.y)*(At.y-F.y)<7.*7.) {
        fragColor = vec4(0.,0.,0.,0.);
    } else if((At.x-F.x)*(At.x-F.x)+(At.y-F.y)*(At.y-F.y)<12.*12.) {
        fragColor = vec4(1.,1.,1.,1.);
    }

    fragColor+=degColor;

    for(int i = 0; i<pointNum ; i++) {
        vec2 T = points[i];
        if((T.x-F.x)*(T.x-F.x)+(T.y-F.y)*(T.y-F.y)<4.*4.) {
            fragColor = vec4(1.,0.,0.,1.);
        }
    }

    gl_FragColor = fragColor;
}

vec3 cubicsolve(float a,float b,float c,float d) {
    vec3 x = vec3(-1.,-1.,-1.);

    if (a == 0.) {
        //fragColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,0.);
        if(b == 0.) {
            if(c == 0.) {

                return x;
            }
            x.x = -d/c;
            return x;
        }
        float delta = c*c+4.*b*d;
        if(delta>0.) {
            delta = sqrt(delta);
            x.x = (-c+delta)/(2.*b);
            x.y = (-c-delta)/(2.*b);
        } else if(delta == 0.) {
            x.x = -c/(2.*b);
        }
        return x;
    }

    if (d == 0.) {
        //fragColor = vec4(0.0,1.0,0.0,0.);
        x.x = 0.;
        float delta = b*b+4.*a*c;
        if(delta>0.) {
            delta = sqrt(delta);
            x.y = (-b+delta)/(2.*a);
            x.z = (-b-delta)/(2.*a);
        } else if(delta == 0.) {
            x.y = -b/(2.*a);
        }
        return x;
    }
    b /= a;
    c /= a;
    d /= a;
    float disc, q, r, dum1, s, t, term1, r13;
    q = (3.0*c - (b*b))/9.0;
    r = -(27.0*d) + b*(9.0*c - 2.0*(b*b));
    r /= 54.0;
    disc = q*q*q + r*r;
    x.x = 0.; //The first root is always real.
    term1 = (b/3.0);
    if (disc > 0.) { // one root real, two are complex
        s = r + sqrt(disc);
        s = ((s < 0.) ? -pow(-s, (1.0/3.0)) : pow(s, (1.0/3.0)));
        t = r - sqrt(disc);
        t = ((t < 0.) ? -pow(-t, (1.0/3.0)) : pow(t, (1.0/3.0)));
        x.x = -term1 + s + t;
        return x;
    } 
    // End if (disc > 0)
    // The remaining options are all real
    if (disc == 0.){ // All roots real, at least two are equal.
        r13 = ((r < 0.) ? -pow(-r,(1.0/3.0)) : pow(r,(1.0/3.0)));
        x.x = -term1 + 2.0*r13;
        x.y = -(r13 + term1);
        x.z = x.y;
        return x;
    } // End if (disc == 0)
    // Only option left is that all roots are real and unequal (to get here, q < 0)
    q = -q;
    dum1 = q*q*q;
    dum1 = acos(r/sqrt(dum1));
    r13 = 2.0*sqrt(q);
    x.x = -term1 + r13*cos(dum1/3.0);
    x.y = -term1 + r13*cos((dum1 + 2.0*3.14159265359)/3.0);
    x.z = -term1 + r13*cos((dum1 + 4.0*3.14159265359)/3.0);
    return x;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a bunch of floating point errors, but I have no idea what to do about it

Comment: Could be caused by precision issues. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366416/in-opengl-es-2-0-glsl-where-do-you-need-precision-specifiers

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, which is as obnoxious as opengl can get. While some time ago precision specifiers were still accepted but useless on desktop, for compatibility with opengl-es that still supports and needs these specifiers. So they decided to make it impossible to include a precision specifier on desktop glsl which means I spent two hours looking for a way to up the precision on mobile, but it wouldn't compile. I now need to make two different shaders : one for desktop, one for es.

The solution was to simply add the following at the very top of the code :

```
precision highp float;
```

while it still isn't desktop precision, it's enough for me.